# Electrical breaker popping

Tags: electrical, receptacle, circuit-breaker

I bought a small house from about 1970 (or there about.) It currently has only one receptacle in the living room and well I will admit I am most likely overloading this receptacle as my computer, TV, Game system, Monitor, and internet/wifi, are all plugged into the same spot. I know this is not a good idea to have them all one the same plug, especially since my plug has tripped once already. But is there any easy fix to this issue?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Northern Nevada

Comment: Are there any other outlets on this circuit? Particularly ones running space heaters... I wouldn't expect that much load to trip a breaker.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an issue I recently faced. My wife was drying her hair in our bathroom. Two of my children were taking a shower (running the lights and fans). Circuit breaker popped and that half of the house went dark. Turns out someone had spliced into the light circuit inside the attic (the attic lights made it easy) to add these extra outlets to the bathroom. My wife, who had the misfortune of picking one of these outlets (she has an original outlet on a different circuit), put the circuit over amps.

My guess is your lonely outlet has some friends, and may be a "We need an outlet here" hack into a smaller circuit. Determine what is on this circuit first. If you're sharing your circuit with, say, a refrigerator, that could be a big problem.

One way to potentially solve this is, if it's an interior wall adjoining another room, to see if there's an outlet on the other side of the wall (on a different circuit, or you'll just exacerbate your single outlet problem). If you have this type of setup, measure to where the outlet will be along the living room side (make sure you figure out where the studs are as well). Then you can use an old work drywall box and fish a wire through the hole into the existing box and splice off of it. I've done this myself and it's a great way to add more outlets without having to do any extensive wire work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are over-loading the circuit (as opposed to the breaker is damaged and tripping low), there is no EASY fix.

Things you CAN do:

- Move some of that gear to a circuit in another room.
- Get an electrician to install a second circuit into that room. Depending on circumstances that may be kind of expensive.
- Make sure to completely shut off anything you aren't using. A power strip with individual switches for each outlet could help here. When the computer is shut down, kill it's power at the strip. Same for the TV and monitor - kill the one you aren't using. That should reduce the likelyhood of tripping the breaker.
- Procure lower-powered versions of all these devices. This may be difficult, expensive, or impossible, depending on your devices. For instance, if your TV is of recent vintage, it may already BE as power efficient as it can be. A device like a [Kill-A-Watt](http://www.p3international.com/products/p4400.html) meter (there are several on the market, I think) will help with tracking down the biggest offenders.

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself a meter such as the ["Kill-a-Watt" for ~$25](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B000RGF29Q/ref=s9u_simh_gw_i2?ie=UTF8&fpl=fresh&pd_rd_i=B000RGF29Q&pd_rd_r=Z3VRHDKHF5Z8XW21J2K0&pd_rd_w=GmEU7&pd_rd_wg=QcQyq&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=desktop-1&pf_rd_r=2VEH9X822BYB7GV4W635&pf_rd_r=2VEH9X822BYB7GV4W635&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=781f4767-b4d4-466b-8c26-2639359664eb&pf_rd_p=781f4767-b4d4-466b-8c26-2639359664eb&pf_rd_i=desktop) to measure how much power each of your devices is using.  You can plug in one item at a time (or several with a power strip/splitter bar). Measure each device sharing that circuit and you'll soon have a sense of how much power each of them takes.

The most interesting number will probably be **amps** (a USA circuit supports 15 or 20, the circuit breaker says which).  You do not want to allow the total of devices on a circuit to exceed that number.

Exceeding the current rating of the wiring, will cause a fire hazard, even if the breaker trips and you keep resetting it.  It or a proper fuse limits the current and bring the load to your attention when the fuse is tripped.

[image]

If you want to work with **watts**, then use the Kill-a-Watt's figure for **VA**.  It also has watts, but VA is more realistic.   Divide by 120 (in North America) for amps.

If you notice which outlets go out when you turn off a breaker, you can map which outlets are on which circuit.  Map each circuit.  That, with the amp usage of your appliances, will explain why your breaker trips and give you hints as to how to rearrange things.

It's real common for a house to have 4 receptacle circuits with all the loads piled on one circuit, just because of dumb luck.  Once you know, it can be an easy fix.   But you can't know until you test.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are spot on, may I offer you a suggestion.    Every house I buy I make a floorplan and turn off all the breakers and then turn one on at a time and test every socket light and built in you have and make a map of all the circuits with it.  It will make locating whats what in junction boxes while in the attic and will be a godsend if anything ever does go out.  I'm renovating a 107 year old house and upon doing this before move in I found 2 plugs that were hot from 2 different breakers and make sure to test upper and lower sockets sometime people do odd things with one circuit to each side of the plug. Also one of those cheap plug in circuit testers will tell you if it's wired correctly and test GFCI's also.